# How to modify menus items in WMD editor forks?

Tags: wmd, wmd-editor

I am just getting into the WMD editor varieties out there :) Of all of them I like MarkEdit because of the ability to modify the menu items quite easily, but it doesn't do a couple of things that I really like in a couple of forks, for example, http://github.com/openlibrary/wmd.

Ideally my perfect WMD editor would:

1. create list items automatically on pressing return when in a list block (not implemented in MarkEdit)
2. allow the removal of menu items (implemented in MarkEdit)
3. the cheat of making a newline without the need for two spaces (implemented in MarkEdit)

As point 1. and 2. are both quite important to me, but I imagine 1. is harder to implement, I may have to use the forks such as the openlibrary-wmd rather than my preferred choice of MarkEdit.

How can I modify the menu buttons in a fork like openlibrary-wmd? The configuration function no longer seems to work as described for the original.

Comment: Having now had a closer look at the code of the openlibrary-wmd, and the markedit version, it is as I suspected and going to be easier to hack the menu of openlibrary version, rather than transfer its list handling functionality to markedit. A dirty hack of makeSpritedButtonRow may be on the cards...

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the markitup editor and found the skin implementation pretty useful. Each skin has its own images and styles which you can easily override if you need to. The editor is also jQuery-driven, which is nice if you're used to that syntax. Check it out

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but I have already tried markitup. It just doesn't do markdown in a friendly enough manner for my end users (a large,diverse bunch of non-IT people that will not have training in markdown or wysiwym editors.) But I have modified the OL-fork of WMD to pretty do what I want for this project ;)
I think for the next project that I need the input stored as text I will use markdownify and markdown-php to sit between the user and a wysiwyg editor